# How to convert ionic 3 code to ionic 4 ? NavParms

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I have created a service that has has a paramater named "code" in ionic 3 
I am confused how to change the same code in ionic 4 ?

How do you catch the code and push it in the firebase in ionic 4 ?

I have similar service that i have in ionic 4 but i dont know how to pull it. I have tried a bunch of method but it doensnt work .

```
submitQuiz(questions: Questions){
  var code = this.navParams.get('code');
  console.log(code);
  for (var z = 0; z < this.i; z++) {
    console.log(questions[z]);
   this.questions$.push({
    code: code,
     question: questions[z]
   });

  }
```

This is my service

```
export interface Quiz {
    code: String;
  }
  export interface Users {
      email: String;
      password: String;
      nickname: String;
  }
  export interface Questions{
      code: String;
      question: any;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try this guide? https://www.joshmorony.com/implementing-a-master-detail-pattern-in-ionic-4-with-angular-routing/ Josh describes how you could leverage shared service to pass data. If you can share your code of the service and components and this is easy to "fix"

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I have posted my service file . I am not sure what you mean by my component file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
  import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ...
  ) { }

  submitQuiz(questions: Questions) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const code = params.code;
      console.log(code);
      for (let z = 0; z < this.i; z++) {
        console.log(questions[z]);
        this.questions$.push({
          code: code,
          question: questions[z]
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The loop could be improved with a forEach()

```
  submitQuiz(questions: Questions) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const code = params.code;
      console.log(code);
      questions.forEach((question) => {
        this.questions$.push({
          code: code,
          question: question
        });
      });
    });
  }
```